# Android ImageButton Stops Firing After Changing Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am making an app using Android Studio where you can listen to downloaded music, and upload music to the cloud. Currently, I am trying to make a button to add a playlist. Here is the home fragment, where the add button is located:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Home Fragment"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/new_playlist"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_new" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As seen above, the button is the ImageButton icon.
Here is the code for adding the onClick event:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    ImageButton imgBtn = findViewById(R.id.new_playlist);
    imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new NewPlaylistFragment()).commit();
        }
    });

}
```

This works fine, displaying the NewPlaylistFragment. The issue is when I use the navigation menu and click on the home fragment. When attempting to hit the new playlist button a second time, nothing happens. When replacing the fragment stuff with a simple Toast message, it fires every time I hit the button. After doing more investigation, I found that changing to the profile fragment and coming back to the home fragment renders the new playlist button useless, regardless the code inside the onclick function. In case it helps, here is the code for the navigation redirection:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new HomeFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_profile:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new ProfileFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_email:
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"person@example.com"});
            startActivity(emailIntent);
            break;
    }
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

My only guess is that changing fragments causes the onClick event to disappear, but I don't know how to fix this.

**Edit**

I tried adding the onClick when a new home fragment object is created, but the problem still persisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `findViewById(R.id.new_playlist)` from the first instantiated `HomeFragment`.
You must find it (and `setOnClickListener`) every time you instantiate a new one.

```
case R.id.nav_home:
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment())
            .commit();
    imgBtn = findViewById(R.id.new_playlist);
    imgBtn.setOnClickListener(onClickListner);
    break;
```

Above is a quick fix. But ideally, I think, you should not handle the finding of the `Button` and `setOnClickListener` in your `Activity` but in your `HomeFragment` class.

Additionally, about your code, every time `R.id.nav_home` or `R.id.nav_profile` selected, a new `HomeFragment` or a new `ProfileFragment` will be spawned.

To avoid multiple spawning of Fragment, use a **tag** String and `findFragmentByTag` (or `findFragmentById`).

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment homeFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(HomeFragment.TAG);
if (homeFragment == null) {
    homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
}
fragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, homeFragment, HomeFragment.TAG)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

(In the above sample, the HomeFragment.TAG is a String constant (static final String).

Comment: When trying to apply the click listener to the button, it creates a NullPointerException (the button is null) The only way I found to prevent this is to put it inside the onStart method. However, then I can't apply the click listener directly after setting the fragment.

Comment: @mega12345mega Then, you may better try to implement the `findViewById` and `setOnClickListener` procedure inside of HomeFragment class (onCreateView or onViewCreated).

Comment: Applying the onClick listener didn't work inside onCreateView, but it worked inside onViewCreated. Thanks for your help and pointers!